# SVG image errors occur while rendering in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg, icons

**It shows the error message like this.**
The following assertion was thrown while parsing AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#9940f(), name: "assets/icons/academy.svg", colorFilter: null, theme: SvgTheme(currentColor: null, fontSize: 14.0, xHeight: 7.0)) in _getDefinitionPaint:
Failed to find definition for url(#pattern0)

This library only supports  and xlink:href references that are defined ahead of their references.

This error can be caused when the desired definition is defined after the element referring to it (e.g. at the end of the file), or defined in another file.

This error is treated as non-fatal, but your SVG file will likely not render as intended

**My SVG file containing images image.svg**

```
<svg width="69" height="69" viewBox="0 0 69 69" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<rect x="16" y="19" width="37" height="31" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
<defs>
<pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
<use xlink:href="#image0_42_579" transform="translate(0 -0.030613) scale(0.00221729 0.00264645)"/>
</pattern>
<image id="image0_42_579" width="451" height="401" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAcMAAAGRCAYAAAAZwNgiAAAgAElEQVR4Aex9B3iV1Zb2NzN35s7cf+7c+8/8c1VARUSaIgiIBRAVRdELtotdJCfoVa9iA6lJvvTek5Oek957L6T33nsjvRACXDcN74r1xD7gX3BPuDfeIe+3s55LfEwQEAUX5/+1kjN9Wr/KbAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"/>
</defs>
</svg>
```

**And image.svg is displayed in display.dart as**

```
class Display extends StatelessWidget {
  const Display({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('icons')),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          SvgPicture.asset(
            'assets/images/image.svg',
            height: 400.0,
            width: 300.0,
            allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: double click on your svg from project explorer and see if svg opens or it show "Image not loaded"

Answer (score 3):

please check your SVG before using it

please go through the link

https://www.svgviewer.dev/

Your image has some issues

Answer (score 1):

My Suggestion is First download the Svg image in file formate then add the package `flutter_svg: ^1.0.3` in `pubspec.yaml`

add the Svg image in assets folder.

Then use it in the project

```
final String assetName = 'assets/image.svg';
final Widget svg = SvgPicture.asset(
  assetName,
  semanticsLabel: 'Acme Logo'
);
```

Comment: rly? I suppose they've done it and faced with following error before asking a question

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting this kind of error.

```
url(#paint0_linear_8372_53236) not found
```

Then just find the content in svg code by opening it in any svg editor(vs code or any online tool)

And move the definition to top wherever it get called.